# What is the difference between 2.4GHz and 5GHz channels

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-access-point

1. Why 2.4G channels are like 1,2,3,4,5 and why 5G channels are like
   36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64 & what is main difference between them ?
2. 4G & 5G for real user ?

Answer (score 1):

As an end user, the benefits of 2.4GHz:

- It has a longer range than 5GHz
- More devices have support for it

And for 5GHz

- There is less interference partly due to less devices using this frequency.

A lot of devices can cause interference on the 2.4GHz range, such as microwaves and home phones.

As for the difference in channel numbering, each channel represents a small frequency range within the main range. For example, although 2.4GHz is called 2.4GHz, the legally allowed Wireless Channels simply start at this frequency, with Channel 14 (Not widely used) sitting around 2.484GHz. Each channel represents it's own section on the 2.4GHz or 5GHz band, and has it's own channel number assigned to it within that band.

Typically, if you're in a small enough area and all your devices support it, you'll get less interference using 5GHz. If you want to cover a larger area or want maximum compatibility, use a 2.4GHz band.

Further reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_WLAN_channels

Comment: Why 2.4G channels are like 1,2,3,4,5 and why 5G channels are like 36,40,44,48,52,56,60,64.?. why dont be 5G channels like 36,37,38,39,40?

Comment: @SANTHOSHRAMIDI It's based on the actual frequency. The 5GHz range starts at 5000MHz, each channel is +5MHz. So channel 36 = 5180MHz. 2.4GHz seems to start at 2407MHz, so each channel is 5MHz steps above that, EG, channel 11 = 2462MHz.

Comment: Note that channels 2.4Ghz channels 12-14, inclusive, are NOT ALLOWED TO BE USED in many regulatory domains, including the United States.  Also, in some jurisdictions (like the United States), a large chunk of 5Ghz channels are only allowed using DFS, to reduce interference with other sources, particular air traffic control radar systems.